# open a bootstrap modal on form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a project with bootstrap modal. All I want is to show one of my modal when a form fill all the fields and press "Complete Subscription" button.

```
<form id="my_form">
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" required>
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last name" required>
    <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>

    <input class="pull-right" type="submit" name="submit" value="Complete Subscription">
</form>
```

I have tried this code. but it's not working.

```
$('#my_form').submit(function () {
    $('#wellcome-modal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Can you provide us the complete code!!

Comment: what do you mean by "it's not working"? Is some element named `wellcome-modal` existing?

Comment: this will not show you the modal after form submission     $('#my_form').submit(function () {$('#wellcome-modal').modal('show');}); reason after submission page reload so i would suggest you should submit form with Ajax method and on success show modal

Comment: sideNote: your modals have scrolling issue with page scroll, so you fixed it too, very annoying when modal open half hidden and on scroll down first page behind modal scroll and when it hits bottom then modal start scrolling down and same happen when scroll up.

Comment: This site is under developed. we have notice this issue and will fix soon. Thank you.

Comment: You have to submit the form through AJAX to show up the modal. Technically if you do it as mentioned above: once the form submits the page reloads, thus hiding the modal, If you need help with AJAX form submission, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

`return false` from the anonymous function to prevent the page from reloading, or call the `preventDefault` method on the event object it receives.

```
$('#my_form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#wellcome-modal').modal('show');
});
```

This assumes you're using Ajax to post the form.